# How to Inject service in HttpServlet in JHipster?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I am working in JHipster Project. I want to inject our service in HttpServlet. But I inject or used it the return null pointer exception please help or Provider way to inject our spring service in HttpServlet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your servlet using a Spring DelegatingFilterProxy.